# Discord JDA dependency missing

Tags: java, maven, pom.xml, discord, discord-jda

I am trying to build a discord application but it can't access the JDA for some reason. Here's the error:

```
The POM for net.dv8tion:JDA:jar:3.6.2_362 is missing, no dependency information available
```

EDIT: Here's my POM:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.mycompany</groupId>
    <artifactId>DiscordBot</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.dv8tion</groupId>
            <artifactId>JDA</artifactId>
            <version>3.6.2_362</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>jcenter</id>
            <name>jcenter-bintray</name>
            <url>http://jcenter.bintray.com</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
</project>
```

Comment: Could we have your pom.xml?

Comment: I just edited it to include the POM

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [JDA's README](https://github.com/DV8FromTheWorld/JDA#download) the newest version at the moment is `3.6.0_362` not `3.6.2_362`, so you might want to change that.

Answer (score 0):

Below is an example JDA maven pom file

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.mycompany</groupId>
<artifactId>DiscordBot</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>bot</name>
<description>General purpose bot</description>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.dv8tion</groupId>
        <artifactId>JDA</artifactId>
        <version>3.6.0_362</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.jagrosh</groupId>
        <artifactId>jda-utilities</artifactId>
        <version>2.1</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
        <type>pom</type>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>jcenter</id>
        <name>jcenter-bintray</name>
        <url>http://jcenter.bintray.com</url>
    </repository>
    <repository>
        <id>central</id>
        <name>bintray</name>
        <url>http://jcenter.bintray.com</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>
```

Answer (score 0):

Why would you use such an old version?

That the newest from https://github.com/DV8FromTheWorld/JDA and https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.dv8tion/JDA/5.0.0-alpha.3

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>net.dv8tion</groupId>
    <artifactId>JDA</artifactId>
    <version>5.0.0-alpha.3</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<properties>
    <maven.compiler.source>17</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>17</maven.compiler.target>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
</properties>



<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.json</groupId>
        <artifactId>json</artifactId>
        <version>20160810</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sparkjava</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.9.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.dv8tion</groupId>
        <artifactId>JDA</artifactId>
        <version>5.0.0-alpha.3</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.5.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.3</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>shade</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <artifactSet>
                            <excludes>
                                <exclude>example</exclude> <!-- You may add jars to exclude from shading -->
                            </excludes>
                        </artifactSet>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

`enter code here`

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).